# Vue+Semanti-UI: modal element changed,only can run seccuess once

Tags: semantic-ui, vuejs2

```
<button class="ui button" @click="beforeAdd">添加</button>

<div class="ui modal">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="description">
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui negative right labeled icon button">
            取消
            <i class="remove icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
            提交
            <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

view methods:

```
beforeAdd(){
    const modal = $(this.$el).find('.ui.modal')
    console.log(modal)
    modal.modal('show')
}
```

first click,modal show, second click nothing happened, I found semantic change modal to root for div class='ui dimmer modals page transition hidden',how can solve it

Comment: Possible to create a fiddle of it?

Comment: @Saurabh https://jsfiddle.net/Dreampie/6tm76fus/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantic is removing it from your `$(this.$el)` so next time it does not find it.

It works when you use with global `$` and an id:

```
show(){
  const showModal = $('#mymodal')
  console.log(showModal)
  showModal.modal('show')
}
```

See Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tm76fus/2/).

Comment: @Dreampie You can do this without changing Path as well : https://jsfiddle.net/6tm76fus/3/

Comment: @Dreampie An other approach can be to save the modal in a variable when it is mounted and use it later, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6tm76fus/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to use Vue variables in your modal, it is necessary to clone the modal and only show the cloned version.

With this approach Vue will still be able to keep track of the original modal, because Semantic doesn't remove it from the DOM.

```
beforeAdd(){
    const modal = $(this.$el).find('.ui.modal').clone()
    console.log(modal)
    modal.modal('show')
}
```